# Are questions about malfunctioning development software legitimate?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question, questions, asking-questions

Well, yesterday, a question was complaining about something wrong in MS Visual C++ Express; mind you, not code. Here's the question:

> Working on a windows forms project in MS C++ express 2010. It builds
>   fully with no errors, runs correctly as a forms based application but
>   in the solution explorer the icon for form1.h shows it as a header
>   file - with the h icon, rather than with the form icon. The only
>   answer I can come up with is I've changed/deleted something while
>   trying to solve another problem - but what - I need to add more
>   buttons!

Now I commented that this type of question is not meeting Stack Overflow's standards, but many external users, not the OP, said that "no" that was a legitimate question... One [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442722/lost-design-view-in-c-express-2010?noredirect=1#comment35944508_23442722) said:

> @Abdullah0v0: I believe you're incorrect. Why then does the 'Eclipse'
>   tag exist? For questions about nothing but the IDE!

The question was even upvoted...
That was a real eye-opener for me, and I came here to make sure, are these questions allowed? Don't they belong on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: Actually, every programming question is about the tool called compiler (or interpreter).

Comment: No @DanubianSailor, most programming questions are not specific to compilers or interpreters. Languages exist outside of any implementation of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, checking the Help Center can be useful.

So if you look at the [What questions can I ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you will see the following (sans the free-hand red circle)

> [image: screenshot of help center with tools commonly used by programmers circled]

Questions about the tools programmers use are considered on-topic, and an IDE would certainly be a tool commonly used by a programmer.

Comment: Well, the help center it is, the next time!

Comment: What do you mean, "sans" the freehand red circle? It's right there in the page. I can see it.

Comment: @BoltClock you are taking that phrase out of context: "So if you look at the What questions can I ask here you will see the following...."

Comment: @psubsee2003: I was trying to make a joke that the freehand circle also appeared on the help center page, but I guess that didn't work ;)

Comment: @BoltClock I was thinking to myself that you were probably joking as I typed my reply, so it did work - but I wasn't 100% sure, so I hit submit on the comment.

Answer (score 4):

To quote directly from the site's listing of what is relevant and on-topic, in the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) pages:

> ***What topics can I ask about here?***
>
> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development
>
> then you’re in the right place to ask your question!